# If there are plane filling curves, are there volume-filling planes?

Tags: general-topology

Not a mathematician, so don't know if this question even makes sense.

But if you can tessellate a plane (which is 2d) with a line (1d), can you extend the concept to higher dimensions?

How would that look like?

Comment: Obviously, extruding a plane filling curve so it's infinitely wide does the job. But even better, there are (1d) curves that fill spaces of arbitrarily many dimensions!

Comment: I was wondering if just extruding like that would count... Are there more... "wobbly" planes like that, which are not just extrusions of a curve? And does that mean that any n-dimensional space can be filled with a construction of *any* lower dimension?

Comment: That I don't know, which is part of why I only commented.

Comment: @Dan Uznanski: For those interested --- Jean-Armand Marie Joseph de Séguier (1862-1935), [*Courbe remplissant un cube à* $n$ *dimensions*](http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1901__29__312_1.pdf) [Curve filling a cube of $n$ dimensions], **Bulletin de la Société Mathématique de France** 29 (1901), 312-314. I'm pretty sure it was well known that extensions to higher dimensions can be made, as Peano mentions a continuous curve filling a $3$-dimensional cube at the end of his 1890 paper. I believe what de Séguier did was to carry out the details for a generalization of Hilbert's 1891 approach.

Answer (score 2):

Usually a space-filling curve is understood to be a continuous surjection $u : I \to I \times I$ (where $I = [0,1]$). If you want, you can use $u$ to construct a continuous surjection $v : \mathbb{R} \to  \mathbb{R}^2$.

An immediate consequence is that we can find continuous surjections  $u^m_n : I^m \to I^n$ whenever $m \le n$ (similarly $v^m_n : \mathbb{R}^m \to  \mathbb{R}^n$).

To see this, we start with $m = 1$ and define $u^1_n$ inductively by $u^1_1 = id$ and
$$u^1_{n+1} : I \stackrel{u^1_n}{\rightarrow} I^n = I^{n-1} \times I \stackrel{id \times u}{\rightarrow} I^{n-1} \times I^2 = I^{n+1} .$$
If $p_m : I^m \to I$ denotes projection to the first coordinate, we set
$$u^m_n = u^1_n \circ p_m .$$
In your question you use the wording "tessalation". Usually this is a tiling of a plane using one or more geometric shapes ("tiles") such that no point is contained in the interior of more than one tile. You can generalize this concept to higher dimensions, but you must be aware that space filling curves do not really have a relation to tessalations in that sense.