# Are there hilbert space filling surfaces (2D) / volumes (3D) / (N-D)?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fractals

If I understand correctly Hilbert space filling curves only map N dimensions to 1.

However, I'm looking for a similar concept, that maps N dimensions to X dimensions. (My choice of how many).

And ideally has the same nice properties as Hilbert space filling curves (good locality preservation).

Is there some generalization of Hilbert space filling curves?

This would give greater granularity over the traversal of the state space / degrees of freedom / dimensions.

It would allow compression of 100 dimensions down to 50, or 25, etc.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2973067/if-there-are-plane-filling-curves-are-there-volume-filling-planes This question is the same as this one.